# MatDatePicker - Show Days From Other Months

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

Using [MatDatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker), how can I make it show days from prior and future months? I checked the angular documentation, google and Stack Overflow but was unable to find an answer myself.

Comment: It's impossible. MatDatePicker use the space of prior days to show the name of the month.